# Mkdir cria diretórios sem permissão

Tags: php, file-permission

Tenho um sistema de upload onde é criado um diretório da seguinte forma:

```
$diretorio = mkdir("../../arquivos/".$anoEdicao,0777);
```

Por ex.: Ele cria o diretório **arquivos/2018**.

O problema é que mesmo o diretório do sistema ter permissão 777 ( estou usando localmente ), o diretório do upload é criado, porém sem permissão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei reforçar com o comando abaixo:

```
chmod($diretorio, 0777);
```

mas de nada adiantou e com isso não é feito o upload.

```
if(move_uploaded_file($temp,$diretorio."/".$codArquivo)){
....
}
```

Como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: @vnbrs creio que seja isso mesmo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `umask` é o comando que determina as configurações de uma máscara que controla que permissão de arquivo será dada a arquivos novos criados no sistema. Cada processo no sistema operacional tem sua própria máscara.

Já que a criação de arquivos e diretórios é afetada pela configuração do `umask`, você pode criar arquivos com permissões como quiser se manipulá-lo da seguinte forma:

```
$antigo = umask(0);
$diretorio = mkdir("../../arquivos/".$anoEdicao,0777);
umask($antigo);
```

Veja que mudo o `umask` para `0` e então volto ao seu antigo valor, para evitar qualquer problema futuro.

[**Se quiser saber mais do `umask`, veja aqui.**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44542/what-is-umask-and-how-does-it-work) E a [**documentação do PHP sobre ele.**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php)

Comment: Muito bom. Não conhecia o `umask()`. Funcionou para mim. Muito obrigado vnbrs.